# convert code from objective c to swift:MJPopUpViewController

Tags: ios, swift

How to convert the code given below from ObjectiveC to swift:

```
-(void)presentPopupViewController:(UIViewController*)popupViewController animationType:(MJPopupViewAnimation)animationType dismissed:(void(^)(void))dismissed
```

?

Answer (score 1):

This is how this object-c code would look like in swift

```
func presentPopupViewController(popupViewController: UIViewController, animationType: MJPopupViewAnimation, dismissed:()->())
```